# How to add a custom dictionary to Microsoft SQL Full Text Search?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am struggling with how to get Microsoft SQL Full Text Search to search against words that have word breakers in them such as A-123, AB-123, or ABC-123. The out of the box English word breaker wants to split these words at the dash. The words with dashes in them are a known set. I came across [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlfts/2009/12/03/creating-custom-dictionaries-for-special-terms-to-be-indexed-as-is-in-sql-server-2008-full-text-indexes/) which discusses a possible solution, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am running SQL 2014 Enterprise Edition with SP 1. I created a text file with the following contents:
A-123
AB-123 
ABC-123

I then restarted the full text service using exec sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts'.

I then tested to see if the solution worked by executing select [display_term],* from sys.dm_fts_parser('ABC-123', 1033,0,0). If working properly I would expect this to return 1 row (exact match for abc-123), but it is still returning 4 rows (abc-123, abc, 123, nn123)

The previous article mentions files that have to be copied and settings that have to be changed. My windows 10 workstation only had NlsData0009.dll and NlsLexicons0009.dll (which I did copy to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn). NlsGrammars0009.dlll was not on my workstation. Feels like these instructions are too specific to SQL 2008.

Assuming I can get the custom dictionary to work I will then need to figure out how to apply a different custom dictionary to each database. There is sql servers with multiple databases where each database would need its own copy of a custom dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

The Custom Dictionary file you create needs to be named `"Custom0009.lex"` for English, and placed in the following directory, where `"C:\Program Files"` is the install path of your SQL Instance:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance>\MSSQL\Binn`

It is important to note the dictionary file you create **HAS** to be Unicode-encoded, SQL Server will simply ignore it if not.

For other languages you need to change the `"0009"` part of the file name according to the **Language hexadecimal code** in Table 2 of this article: [Create a custom dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc263242(v=office.14)#supported-languages)

Unfortunately the Custom Dictionary file is universal across the entire SQL instance so won't be possible to have a different one per database.  The only solution here would be to create an instance for each database.